# Playing multiple continuous tones on Arduino

Tags: audio, timer, arduino

I am working on a project for college. It involves an Arduino Pro Trinket, and is supposed to be an instrument of some kind.

The premise is that you will have 4 potentiometers which will change the pitch of 4 tones. These tones will be enabled/disabled by one button each. The tones can be played on any number of piezos, however the less the better.

I'm aware that Arduinos do not have sufficient timers to play multiple tones, however in my case, timers are not necessary.

I'm pretty much brand new to Arduino; I do, however, get the basics of using potentiometers with them which is the only other difficult part.

Am I complicating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino Pro Trinket uses an Atmega328P processor, which has three timers with two outputs per timer. One timer is used by the core, which leaves enough outputs for your application.

If you want to play concurrent tones on different pins, using the timers is probably the easiest way to go, but you can roll your own algorithm, and there are libraries available for this as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Would you be able to point me in the way of any resources on how to do this, please?

Thanks~

Comment: There are many PWM libraries out there that can make tones for you; try finding one that will do PWM on 4 pins and can do frequencies up to, say 10kHz. There are also alternative tone libaries. I don't know if your teacher allows the use of libraries, though.

Comment: It is allowed. Are there any recommended libraries? And is it possible to use PWN to play these notes on only 1 speaker?

Comment: I can't recommend any specific libraries, you will have to figure that out yourself. Playing the notes on one speaker requires mixing, which could maybe be done in software, but also in hardware with one opamp. But I don't want to do your project for you ...